# If I run any command on the toplevel window of tkinter, then it get automatically destroyed. I want to keep it unless user destroy it

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I have imported different files as make it as a toplevel in a function. That function is being called in menubar. Whenever I try to login then either if it is successfull or not it directly goes to parent window. Here goes some lines.

```
class Interface:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title('Omen Retail Store')
        self.master.state('zoomed')
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style = ThemedStyle(self.master)
        self.style.set_theme('scidgreen')

        #Here Are some Buttons to call function ignore that#

    def register(self):
        master=Toplevel()
        Register.Register_Interface(master)
        master.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: master.destroy())


    def login(self):
        master=Toplevel()
        Login.Login_Interface(master)
        master.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: master.destroy())
    def images(self):
        master=Toplevel()
        slideshow.Slide_Image(master)
        master.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: master.destroy())

    def admin_login(self):
        master=Toplevel()
        admin_login.Admin_Interface(master)
        master.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: master.destroy())









def main():
    master=Tk()
    root=Interface(master)
    master.wm_attributes('-alpha',1)
    master.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

Comment: Is this really how your code is indented? You should be getting syntax errors way before the code runs.

Comment: @BryanOakley those funtion where inside class but i have not included class so it seems unindented. Check it now but i have ignored some buttons and imports